# openni_launch problems with kinect and asus, electric and fuerte

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried getting openni_launch to work on Ubuntu 12.04 with fuerte and a Kinect, also on 11.10 with electric and Kinect and on 11.10 with an Asus Xtion Pro Live and now on a second computer running 11.10, electric and the Asus camera. I'm convinced that there's got to be something wrong with the package. I've followed the instructions to the letter. Latest attempt with 11.10, electric and Asus Xtion.

Are there known problems? I've spent probably 40 hours trying to get it working and hired an experienced ROS developer who has probably 15-20 hours into trying to get it working. Are there known problems with it? Has the project been abandoned?

```
rosrun openni_launch openni.launch
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named openni.launch below /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_launch
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files, 
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_launch/launch/openni.launch
chris@chris-VirtualBox:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect$ 

rosmake openni_kinect --rosdep-install
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['openni_kinect']                           
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/chris/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120713-101739
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['openni_kinect'] to:
['openni_tracker', 'openni_camera', 'depth_image_proc', 'openni_launch', 'openni', 'nite']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
Failed to find rosdep nite-dev for package nite on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
Failed to find rosdep openni-dev for package openni on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
Failed to find rosdep ps-engine for package nite on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed                        
chris@chris-VirtualBox:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38748/openni_launch-problems-with-kinect-and-asus,-electric-and-fuerte./) by [punching](https://answers.ros.org/users/1882/punching/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it has to be

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

and also in feurte use

```
rosdep install package_name
```

instead of rosmake package_name --rosdep-install

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2